# How to know the degree of rotation of the Fabric.js object?

Tags: fabricjs

If an Object is added on the canvas and is rotated to right or left .How to know the degree of rotation of the Fabric.js object?

Answer (score 5):

`object.getAngle()` will return the angle, and `object.setAngle()` will set the angle.

A negative value means counter-clockwise, and a positive value means clock-wise.

Comment: or you can use `getAngle()`

Comment: A good example that maybe will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884051/right-way-to-rotate-things-with-a-mouse-in-fabric-js

Comment: Will it return angle in degrees or radians?

Comment: @v.j Angle is in degrees.